# Bedeutung von "die sie ihm verhalten" (nicht reflexiv)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Novalis' [*Die Lehrlinge zu Sais*](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.183135/2015.183135.Novalis-Gesammelte-Werke-Erster-Band_djvu.txt) enthält folgenden Satz:

> ...nur sucht der eine hinter diesen blauen, fernen Gestalten noch eine
> Heimat, die sie ihm **verhalten**, ...

Ich brauche Hilfe sowohl mit der Bedeutung des Wortes "verhalten", als auch mit dem Satzbau.

Zum ersten: Bei einer anderen Auflage des Buches steht "verhüllen" anstatt "verhalten". Welche Bedeutung von "verhalten" wäre die, die "verhüllen" am nächsten steht, und die in diesem Satz Sinn ergibt?

Zum zweiten: Mein Gedankengang ist folgender: "die sie ihm verhalten" ist ein Nebensatz, also braucht eine finite Verbform. "Verhalten" als finite Verbform (Präsens) wäre Plural, während das Bezugswort von "die" ist "Heimat", in Singular. Also passt es nicht. Wo liege ich falsch? (Ich habe mir überlegt, ob es sich um eine „afinite Konstruktion“ handeln könnte, wo "hat" oder "hatte" implizit am Ende stehen. Das würde syntaktisch passen, aber die noch nicht gefundene Heimat scheint mir semantisch zum (Plusquam)perfekt nicht besonders gut zu passen)

Comment: Eine Quelle mit *verhalten*: https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10110359_00188.html?zoom=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es ist meines Erachtens hilfreich, einen größeren Ausschnitt des Textes zu betrachten:

> Liegt nun die wundersame sinnliche und unsinnliche Natur rund um uns her, so glauben wir es sei jener Zug ein Anziehn der Natur, eine Äußerung unsrer Sympathie mit ihr: nur sucht der eine hinter diesen blauen, fernen Gestalten noch eine Heimat, **die sie ihm verhalten**, eine Geliebte seiner Jugend, Eltern und Geschwister, alte Freunde, liebe Vergangenheiten; der andre meint, da jenseits warteten unbekannte Herrlichkeiten seiner, eine lebensvolle Zukunft glaubt er dahinter versteckt, und streckt verlangend seine Hände einer neuen Welt entgegen.

---

#### Struktur des Nebensatzes

- Das Relativpronomon ***die*** bezieht sich auf in der Tat auf die *Heimat*, ist aber das **Akkusativobjekt** von *verhalten*.
- **Subjekt** ist hingegen das Personalpronomen ***sie***, das sich auf *diese blauen, fernen Gestalten* bezieht.

Als Hauptsatz hieße der Satz somit:

> Sie<sub>Nom.Pl.</sub> verhalten<sub>3.P.Pl.-Ind.-Präs.-Akt.</sub> sie<sub>Akk.Sg.</sub> ihm<sub>Dat.Sg.</sub>.

– oder:

> Diese blauen, fernen Gestalten verhalten dem einen eine Heimat (welche er sucht).

---

#### Bedeutung von verhalten

Beim Lesen hatte ich die Assoziation *vorenthalten*. Dazu passt, dass das [Deutsche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV01687#XGV01687) der Brüder Grimm (vorgeschlagen als Quelle von @mtwde) *verhalten* zunächst als 'zurückhalten' definiert. Darüber hinaus scheint mir die Bedeutung *(3) festhalten und dadurch verschlieszen, zuhalten* mit dem Beispiel 'hies sü die stroszen verhalten' relevant. In die gleiche Richtung geht auch im übertragenen Sinn *(5) als geistige thätigkeit, das zurückhalten geschieht in der absicht, es wieder hinzugeben, 'vorbehalten'*. Diese beiden dürften *verhüllen* (wie es bei *Project Gutenberg* vorkommt) am nächsten kommen. Der Unterschied ist, dass beim *Vor(ent)halten* und *Zurückhalten* die *blauen Gestalten* im 'Besitz' der *Heimat* sein müssten.

Von den heutigen Bedeutungen des Wortes scheint *(3) etw. zurückhalten, unterdrücken* aus dem [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verhalten#d-1-3), die auch schon Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm (4) kannten, den o.g. am nächsten zu kommen.

In jedem Fall kann *Verhüllen* die Bedeutung nicht grob verzerren, da es im nächsten, parallelistischen Halbsatz über die Zukunft mit einem Fast-Synonym heißt: *eine lebensvolle Zukunft glaubt er dahinter **versteckt***.

Comment: Passender wäre verhalten im Sinne von "verschweigen". Siehe [Grimm verhalten (5)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV01687#XGV01687).

Comment: @mtwde Das *DWB* ist in der Tat eine weitere hervorragende Ressource, die ich noch übernehmen werde – ich habe zunächst nach einer passenden, noch aktiv verwendeten Bedeutung von *verhalten* gesucht. Warum von den vielen darin aufgeführten Bedeutungen ausgerechnet *verschweigen* besser passen sollte, erschließt sich mir jedoch nicht: auch die Brüder Grimm sehen diese nur "bei dingen, die in worte gekleidet werden".

Comment: M.E. trifft es "zurückhalten, unterdrücken" nicht ideal. Es wird nichts vorenthalten, eher vorgehalten. Aus meiner Sicht sind es daher eher die [Grimm'schen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GV01687&hitlist=&patternlist=&mode=Gliederung) Bedeutungen 7 und 8: "beherbergen, Aufenthalt geben" bzw. "verwahren, bewahren".

Comment: @tohuwawohu Es geht doch gerade darum, dass die blauen Gestalten die Heimat (falls dort vorhanden) verdecken und eben *nicht* 'vorhalten'. Siehe oben: *sucht der eine **hinter** diesen blauen, fernen Gestalten*. Zudem kennen die Bedeutungen (7) und (8) aus dem DWB kein Dativobjekt.

Answer (score 0):

This word is simply wrong, probably an error during scanning. The correct word is *verhüllen*:

> ... nur sucht der eine hinter diesen blauen, fernen Gestalten noch eine Heimat, die sie ihm verhüllen, ...

[The text at Project Gutenberg](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/novalis/sais/sais2.html)

Comment: Das kann natürlich immer der Fall sein, doch meine gedruckte Version sagt auch "verhalten". Unabhängig davon: Angenommen, du hast Recht, gilt meine Frage zum Satzbau auch für den korrigierten Satz.